# Can a view "a" appear only in the page of view "b"?

Tags: views

I have a view I want it appears only in the page of another view.

Is it possible without writing code?

Answer (score 2):

Put him in a block and show that block only on the page of the other view.  Or more precisely, create a block display for view a and have it displayed only on the path defined by the page display in view b.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Another View" you can insert any other view into its header or footer. If that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Use **attachments** in the view and attached it with the view which you want.
Instead of creating a new view or block.